# Parent generates scrollbar with positioned child

Tags: css, css-position

Why does applying a top offset property to the last child, with a property of position: relative, cause the parent to generate a scrollbar? There is no fixed height for the parent that would otherwise generate the scrollbar.

https://jsfiddle.net/gn3svh1w/

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="child one"></div>
  <div class="child two"></div>
  <div class="child three"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: auto;
  background: slategrey;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.three {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Remove `overflow: auto` from styles of `.wrap`. This property is causing scroll to appear.

Comment: Your relative positioning is pushing the element out of the parent's wrapper height (defined by the height of the 3 elements). Change `top: 40px` to `margin-top: 40px` to prevent a scrollbar and keep all spacing in the normal flow.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: auto` also contributes. If you take that off (`overflow: visible` is usually default I think?), you will see the red box go outside the bottom bound of the parent container.

Adding `overflow: auto` tells the parent to let the browser decide it's height - FF and other desktops will render scrollbars for this.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow for more info

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this is a question of how browsers determine height. The three inner divs all have a height of 100px and the margin of 1rem. This provides the height of the `.wrap` div.

Now once you set the top position of `.three`, this doesn't change the height calculated by the inner divs. It merely just moves the div down thus causing the scroll bar in `.wrap` to appear.